# Ubuntu 16.04 diskless can't login 2 users same time

Tags: 16.04, login, lightdm, nfs

I need some help.
I have a diskless Ubuntu 16.04 set up via nfs. The issue is that if I boot up 2 computers from the system I can't login them in at the same time, the desktop-manager just resets the screen to the login screen.

Can you help me find a solution to this problem, or could someone explain me why I can't login 2 users same time from my diskless system.

Comment: Are those two different user accounts or the same user account?

Comment: They are 2 different users account.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.